# Parsing USS XML file in Cobol?

Tags: encoding, xml-parsing, cobol, zos

I am using the Cobol XML Parser to parse an xml document that originated from the HFS (USS) file system through batch JCL.

My problem is that the XML Parser is returning "XML DOCUMENT ERROR 0000000317" which seems to be an encoding issue.

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure that the encoding tag on the XML declaration is valid and agrees with what the actual document is.  You will also need to make sure that the LPAR you are running on has the proper code page conversions defined in Unicode Conversion Services for z/OS.

Comment: Joe's first sentence is very important.  If your XML document was created with a declaration that states it is ISO-8859-1 but has been FTPed to z/OS and translated to (say) code page 37, then the COBOL parser (and the z/OS XML System Services parser) are going to have trouble with the dichotomy.

Comment: Actually there is no FTP. I am using java in USS to access a web service. I then save the data to a file. Then I have JCL access the file directly. Is there a way to get Java to save the file in the correct format so that cobol can just read it?

Comment: Joe's second sentence is also very important. Have your sysprog verify the existence of the proper Unicode Conversion Services table. BTDTTS, although with WMQ.

Comment: USS can be set to use an EBCDIC code page by default! Browse the data in hex and see if it really is UTF-8. Hint "0" in UTF-8 = x'30' "0" in EBCDIC = x"F0".